# $G_f = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y \vert y = f(x) \}$ connected $\Leftrightarrow X$ connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $f : (X,\tau) \rightarrow (Y,\tau$') a continuos function such that its graph is $G_f = \{(x,y) \in X \times Y \vert y = f(x) \}$ with the induced topology $\tau \times \tau$'. I need to prove that $G_f$ is connected if and only if X is connected. At first I thought that since the function is continuous $G_f$ is connected by arcs and then it follows that it is connected, but I'm not too sure about this approach because it seems too... simple.

Comment: Your idea is the right ... idea. However, you cannot rely on the existence of nice arcs in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is connected, $G_f$ is the image of $x\rightarrow (x,f(x))$ which is continuous so it is connected since the image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected.

If $G_f$ is connected, the projection $p:X\times Y\rightarrow X$ is continuous and $X=p(G_f)$.

Comment: You could clarify why $x \to (x,f(x))$ is continuous (universal property of products e.g.)